# Parse model and association hasMany from a raw query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

thanks in advance for your hepl.

I have two models Menu and Window with their associations

```
db.menus.hasMany(db.windows);
db.windows.belongsTo(db.windows);
```

I'm trying to make a plane query with a output similar to this:

```
'menu':
{'description':'Menu 1',
     "windows": [
                  {"description": "windows 1"},
                  {"description": "windows 2"},
                  {"description": "windows 3"},      
                ]
}
```

When i put the assosiation hasOne instead of hasMany at least the windows is inside of the menu, but with a row for each windows, but with the hasMany the information is inclued as part of the **menu** and I want a object of the windows.

```
const options = {
        model: db.menus,
        // mapToModel: true,
        // hasJoin: true,
        include: [{
            model: db.ventanas
        }]
    };
    db.menus._validateIncludedElements(options);
    db.sequelize.query(Query, options)
        .then(MenuWindows => {
            console.log(MenuWindows);
        });
```

I have proved a lot of convinations but no one works properly and I wondering if there is something that I havent done, as I said when I put the assosiation **hasOne** the option **hasJoin** works otherwise that give me this error ***Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'model' of undefined***

*BTW, with the findAll the sequelize works fine, but I'm making a complex query with more tables but just showing the menus and windows, so I infer that the association is fine and the problem is with the way I'm mapping the output*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried this...

```
return sequelize.query(/* query */, {
    nest: true,
    type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
});
```

Comment: Yes, I did, and is a little close to the answer I want because at least the output of the window is inside of the object of the menu, but that give a row for each window

`{ menu: { id: 1, description: 'Menu 1' },
    windows: { id: 5, description: 'Usuarios 5', menuId: 1 } },

{ menu: { id: 1, description: 'Menu 1' },
    windows: { id: 1, description: 'Usuarios 1', menuId: 1 } }`

Answer (score 1):

After a thousand of attempts it worked just putting the alias of the table in the model

````
        model: db.menus,
        as: 'menu',
        hasJoin: true,
        include: [{
            as: 'windows',
            model: db.windows
        }]
    };
    db.menus._validateIncludedElements(options);
    db.sequelize.query(query, options)
        .then(menuWindows => {
            console.log(menuWindows);
        }); ```
````

Comment: excellent, and great job posting back your answer so that other people who may encounter something similar may find this helpful!  Cheers